# What's wrong with this code of changing background of an imagebutton?

Tags: android, imagebutton

I am trying to change the image of an imagebutton using the following codes. Eclipse crashes but there is no error discovered… I've also used setBackgroundResource instead of setImageResource, but it didn't work. Nothing in Logcat, nither in errors. Please help me to find the right way.

I have two images for this imagebutton. - edit_on & edit_off
xml

Java

```
    imageblockButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonblock);
    imageblockButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageblockButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.edit_on);
            Intent intent1 = new Intent (context, ActivityBlockList.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            v.setClickable(true);
        }
    });
```

my xml looks like…

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/buttonblock" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="0sp" 
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
    android:background="@drawable/edit_off" />
```

Comment: my xml looks like…                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/buttonblock"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="0sp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_off" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In your xml    
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/buttonblock" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:padding="0sp" 
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
        android:src="@drawable/edit_off" />  

    use src instead of background
    and 
    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonblock);
    btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.newimage);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've tried your suggestion, but it didn't work…
[2013-12-08 18:39:41 - IncomingCallNO] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-12-08 18:39:41 - IncomingCallNO] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched… I am getting the same result.
I think the compiler is NOT working...

Comment: restart your eclipse and emulator

Comment: Restarting works now, except I have another problem, though.
As you see above, By pressing the imagebutton, the screen moves to other activity. However, when I comes back to this screen it shows "the new image" instead of old one. The new image should show when there is a click. Could you help me again on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
imageblockButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edit_on));
```

Comment: Thank you very much… But, it is NOT working yet.
I am getting
[2013-12-08 18:39:41 - IncomingCallNO] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-12-08 18:39:41 - IncomingCallNO] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...